# How To Run Exe From SharePoint 13

Tags: .net, web-parts, exe, sharepoint-2013

I Want to Execute 3rd Party Exe From SharePoint 13
I have written following function in javascript

```
function launchApp() 
{
 appPath ="C:\\Windows\\system32\\sample.exe";
 WSH = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
 WSH.run(appPath);
}
```

i have called this function on hyperlink.
tried with all ActiveX settings in browser.

When i click on hyperlink it gives me Error as :
"Automation server can't create object"

I have tried following Code also using web part:

```
 Process process = new Process();
 process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Notepad.exe");
 process.Start();
```

For this it doesnt give any error but doesn't even execute the exe

Comment: that would be a huge security risk.